# Why is sound mixed by soundmixer plugin truncated?

Tags: c, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I develop in C an application relying on soundmixer plugin. My aim is to trigger sounds on events. As reactivity is critical, I wish to keep gstreamer pipeline alive, and dynamically plug new sounds on the audiomixer element (after applying an offset on the new sink of the mixer).

It works pretty well, except that each time I plug a new sound in, the first 200msec (more or less) of the sound get truncated.

I've been looking into the code, everything looks fine as far as I can see (no mistake on sound plugin, neither on running time/offset applied).

So I made a try on a simple pipeline with gst-launch, with an offset applied on the mixer sink:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/etc/pa/doublclick_aigu_grave.wav ! wavparse ! audiomixer sink_0::offset=1000000000 ! alsasink
```

It turned out that this pipeline truncate the beginning of the sound as well. When I activated the logs with --gst-debug=alsa:5, I got a bunch of logs before sound started :

```
alsa gstalsasink.c:1054:gst_alsasink_write:<alsasink0> written 441 frames out of 441
```

What is going on here ?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Sorry, long time since I logged in. No I didn't solve the issue, finally dropped the soundmixer plugin. Instead I run  several pipelines and let alsasink do the mixing. Easier, but gstreamer spawns many threads, hope it won't lead to resources lack.